# How do I handle async authentication verification and navigation with FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, authentication

Trying setup a authentication checker on my demo app. Currently using the **shared_preferences** package to store the jwt token obtained from a demo api.

I've put together a function that return a Future bool to verify if we have a token stored and if that same is not expired:

```
Future<bool> isUserAuthenticated() async {
    if (tokenIsStored) {
        if (tokenIsNotExpired) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So on the **MyHomePage** state I was thinking on using a FutureBuilder to handle the verification

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Future<bool> isUserAuthenticated = Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () => API().isUserAuthenticated());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: isUserAuthenticated,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          if (snapshot.data as bool) {
            return Text("Hello");
          } else {
            return const LoginPage();
          }
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and over the **LoginPage** I would then request the jwt token and navigate back to **MyHomePage**.

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() => waitingForAPI = true);
    String username = usernameController.text;
    String password = passwordController.text;
    API().login(username, password).then((credsWereValid) {
      if (credsWereValid) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
      }
    });
  }
)
```

Which creates a "always forwarding" flow like:

```
MyHomePage -> LoginPage -> MyHomePage
```

I don't know why but this does not look like a good flow. What I believe is that the correct flow should be is the returning from **LoginPage** with a **Navigator.pop** call:

```
MyHomePage -> LoginPage
MyHomePage <- LoginPage
```

I believe to do so we would need to rework the **MyHomePage** like:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Future<bool> isUserAuthenticated = Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () => API().isUserAuthenticated());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: isUserAuthenticated,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          if (snapshot.data as bool) {
            return Text("Hello");
          } else {
            // return const LoginPage();
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login');
          }
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and the **LoginPage** logic would look like:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() => waitingForAPI = true);
    String username = usernameController.text;
    String password = passwordController.text;
    API().login(username, password).then((credsWereValid) {
      if (credsWereValid) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    });
  }
)
```

My question is which one of theses design patterns should I stick with? Or should pursue another design pattern?

Answer (score 0):

`FutureBuilder` and `Navigator` to me are one-time use auth methods.

There's an easy way to make the process go back and forth smoothly:
Make a `Stream` of the authentication state data in the authentication page,
then use one `Provider` to listen to that data in the transition page.

For a detailed explanation, you can refer to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZYuuGAIwe4&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC&index=4)